# gawk with complex record separator is only printing the first match record

Tags: awk, gawk

The following gawk command is only printing the first match, and I need all of them from the input file.

```
 $ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="{Mon,Tue} Mar {21,22} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} 2016";FS ="\n";OFS="\n"} {print savedRT, $1, $2, $3, $4} {savedRT = RT}' iostat.20160321

Mon Mar 21 20:05:00 2016
 cpu
us sy wt id
4  2  0 94
```

Here is a template for how the input data is formatted:

```
Mon Mar 21 20:05:00 2016
 cpu
us sy wt id
4  2  0 94
...
...
...
Mon Mar 21 20:10:00 2016
 cpu
us sy wt id
3  2  0 94
...
...
...
```

Is there a global flag with gawk? What am I missing?

Comment: That record separator looks suspicious. What do you try to do there?

Comment: I am trying to match the line that includes the date and time. It appears to work, but only for the first record.

Comment: `{Mon,Tue}` is not alternation in a regex. I think your `RS` is never matched, the whole file is seen as a single record, and you just print the first four fields of it (there is also an empty line where `savedRT` is printed, but is the empty string).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Any suggestions to get the regex right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fix this as follows (requires GNU awk<sup>1</sup>):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    RS = "(Mon|Tue) Mar (21|22) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} 2016"
    FS = OFS = "\n"
}
NR > 1 { print savedRT $1, $2, $3, $4 }
{ savedRT = RT }' infile
Mon Mar 21 20:05:00 2016
 cpu
us sy wt id
4  2  0 94
Mon Mar 21 20:10:00 2016
 cpu
us sy wt id
3  2  0 94
```

The following changes were required:

- Change `{Mon,Tue}` and `{21,22}`, in the record separator to `(Mon|Tue)` and `(21|22)` for proper regex alternation
- Only start printing if `NR` is greater than 1; the file starts with a record separator, so the first record is empty and we don't want to print a bunch of empty lines.
- `savedRT` contains a newline, so if we print it like `print savedRT, $1` there will be one newline too many. Changing to `print savedRT $1` removes that extra newline.

---

<sup>1</sup> To be precise, GNU awk 4.0.0 or newer, as the interval expressions `[0-9]{2}` aren't recognized by older gawks, see the [release notes](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-06/msg00013.html). A workaround is to just use `[0-9][0-9]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this and received no output. I replaced gawk for awk in the answer, since awk does not support regexes for record separators.

Comment: Fixed now. The {2} in the regex was the issue, it needs to be [0-9][0-9] instead of [0-9]{2}. I edited the answer and it's awaiting peer review. thanks much for your help.

Comment: @user3155618  It works just the way it is on my awk (GNU awk 4.0.1). I've mentioned that it requires GNU awk; which awk gets called when using `awk` is system dependent.

Comment: @user3155618 FWIW I've accepted the edit and modified it to point out that GNU awk is required, it was about to be rejected, though. The regex shouldn't have to be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am running GNU Awk 3.1.7 which must not handle the  [0-9]{2} properly.

Comment: @user3155618 This was in fact only introduced in gawk 4.0.0, I've added a remark to this end.